# Elastica Filter and Query Array

Tags: elastica

I'm using a form for an advanced search.  The form inputs are representative of the data in the elasticsearch index.  My model receives an array of filter terms and query terms.

```
$data = array(
  'Filter' => array(
    'FilerId' => 14592
  ),
  'Query' => array(
    'FiledDate' => '2015-08-06',
  ),
);
```

I'm using a foreach loop to create the filter and query

```
foreach ($data['Filter'] AS $field => $value) {
    $filter = new \Elastica\Filter\Term();
    $filter->setTerm($field, $value); 
    $filterArray[] = $filter;

}

foreach ($data['Query'] AS $field => $value) {
    $query = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString($value);
    $query->setDefaultOperator('AND')
          ->setDefaultField($field);
    $queryArray[] = $query;

}

$query = new \Elastica\Query();
$query
    ->setFields(['TranId'])
    ->setQuery($queryArray)
    ->setFilter($filterArray);

$search->setQuery($query);


$numberOfEntries = $search->count();
$comma_separated = 0;
if ($numberOfEntries) {
    foreach ($search->scanAndScroll() as $scrollId => $resultSet) {
        $results = $resultSet->getResults();
        $totalResults = $resultSet->getTotalHits();

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $fields = $result->getFields('TransId');
            $transid[] = $fields['TranId'][0];
        }    // ... handle Elastica\ResultSet
    }
    $comma_separated = implode(", ", $transid);
}
return array('transactions' => $comma_separated, 'total' => $totalResults);
```

I am getting an error and I can't find the reason why?

Here is some updated code.  I'm getting results but not what I thought I should get.

```
$boolFilter = new \Elastica\Filter\BoolFilter();

foreach ($data['Filter'] AS $field => $value) {
    $term = new \Elastica\Filter\Term();
    $term->setTerm($field, $value); 
    $boolFilter->addMust($term);
}

$boolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();

foreach ($data['Query'] AS $field => $value) {
    $match = new \Elastica\Query\Match();
    $match->setFieldQuery($field, $value)
          ->setFieldAnalyzer($field, 'whitespace')
          ->setFieldOperator($field, 'AND'); 
    $boolQuery->addMust($match);
}

$query = new \Elastica\Query();
$query
    ->setFields(['TranId'])
    ->setQuery($boolQuery)
    ->setFilter($boolFilter);
//print $error->getError();
print "<pre>";
print_r ($query->toArray());
print "</pre>";
$search->setQuery($query);

$numberOfEntries = $search->count();
$comma_separated = 0;
if ($numberOfEntries) {
    foreach ($search->scanAndScroll() as $scrollId => $resultSet) {
        $results = $resultSet->getResults();
        $totalResults = $resultSet->getTotalHits();

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $fields = $result->getFields('TransId');
            $transid[] = $fields['TranId'][0];
        }    // ... handle Elastica\ResultSet
    }
    $comma_separated = implode(", ", $transid);
    }
    return array('transactions' => $comma_separated, 'total' => $totalResults);
```

Comment: Please tell everyone what error you are getting so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Alright!  I needed to add the Standard analyzer instead of the whitespace analyzer.  The whitespace analyzer works but only breaks the phrase up on spaces.  The standard analyzer breaks the phrase up and make the case lower.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html#analyze-api

```
$boolFilter = new \Elastica\Filter\BoolFilter();

foreach ($data['Filter'] AS $field => $value) {
    $term = new \Elastica\Filter\Term();
    $term->setTerm($field, $value); 
    $boolFilter->addMust($term);
}

$boolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();

foreach ($data['Query'] AS $field => $value) {
    $match = new \Elastica\Query\Match($value);
    $match->setFieldQuery($field, $value); 
    $match->setFieldAnalyzer($field, 'standard');
    $boolQuery->addMust($match);
}

$filterQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Filtered();
$filterQuery->setFilter($boolFilter);
$filterQuery->setQuery($boolQuery);

$query = new \Elastica\Query($filterQuery);
$query->setFields(['TranId']);

print "<pre>";
print_r ($query->toArray());
print "</pre>";

$search->setQuery($query);

$numberOfEntries = $search->count();
$comma_separated = 0;
if ($numberOfEntries) {
    foreach ($search->scanAndScroll() as $scrollId => $resultSet) {
        $results = $resultSet->getResults();
        $totalResults = $resultSet->getTotalHits();

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $fields = $result->getFields('TransId');
            $transid[] = $fields['TranId'][0];
        }    // ... handle Elastica\ResultSet
    }
    $comma_separated = implode(", ", $transid);
    }
    return array('transactions' => $comma_separated, 'total' => $totalResults);
```

Comment: Perfect elastica filter example.